# Выпадающий список php

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите реализовать выпадающий список.
Model:

```
function region_get(){
    $result = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM t_gs_regions  ORDER BY gs_regions_name ASC");
    $n=$result->num_rows;
    for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++) {
         $row6 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
         $regions[] = $row6;                 
    }
    return $regions;
}
```

Controller:

```
$reg = region_get();
```

View:

```
<select name="regions_id">
<option value="">Виберите из списка</option>
<?php foreach ($regions as $r):?> {
    '<option value=<?=$r['gs_regions_id']?>><?=$r['gs_regions_name']?>'</option>';
}
<?php endforeach ?>
} else {
    '<option value="">Список недоступний</option>';
} ?>
</select>
```

Comment: А вопрос в чем? Где у вас проблема? Какая ошибка?

Comment: Список не отображается.Доступно Выберите из списка и Список недоступный

Comment: Сделайте `var_dump($regions);` в конце модели. Массив заполняется?

Comment: И почему у вас в контроллере `$reg`, а во вьюхе `$regions`?

Comment: Во view исправила, var_dump не вывел ничего

Comment: Значит модель из БД не вытаскивает данные

Comment: Спасибо,проверю еще раз

Comment: А тот факт, что в блоке "View" закрывающих тегов `?>` больше чем открывающих вас не смущает? А наличие непонятно откуда и зачем появившихся фигурных скобок (особенно в комплекте с `else`)? Вы бы сначала сделали этот блок валидным куском php кода, а уже потом задавали бы вопросы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас MVC приложение, то должно получиться что-то вроде:

```
<?php
class Model
{
    private $mysqli;

    public function getRegions()
    {
        $result = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM t_gs_regions ORDER BY gs_regions_name ASC");
        $regions = array();
        if ($result) {
            while($row = $this->mysqli->fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $regions[] = $row;
            }
        }

        return $regions;
    }
}
?>

<?php
class Controller
{
    public function regionAction()
    {
        $model = new Model();
        $regions = $model->getRegions();

        return array(
            'regions' => $regions
        );
    }
}
?>

<select name="regions_id">
    <option value="">Виберите из списка</option>
    <?php if (!empty($regions)) :?>
        <?php foreach ($regions as $r) : ?>
            <option value="<?= $r['gs_regions_id']; ?>"><?= $r['gs_regions_name']; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <option value="">Список недоступний</option>';
    <?php endif; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

А если так:

```
function region_get(){
    $result = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM t_gs_regions  ORDER BY gs_regions_name ASC");
    $regions = false;
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
        $regions = array();
        while($row6 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) $regions[] = $row6;
    }
    return $regions;
}
```

И

```
<select name="regions_id">
<option value="">Виберите из списка</option>
<?php if ($regions) { foreach ($regions as $r) {?> {
    '<option value=<?=$r['gs_regions_id']?>><?=$r['gs_regions_name']?>'</option>';
}
<?php } ?>
} else {
    '<option value="">Список недоступний</option>';
} ?>
</select>
```